# Is there a way to implement custom in app upgrade in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I have a few Windows phone 7 app developed with Windows phone 7.1 SDK. Currently, I'm showing ads in all those free apps. I would like to provide an option to remove ads from the app and allow user to buy the app when they click on it. I know there are such in-app purchase api for windows phone 8. Does anyone know anything about similar api in wp7 or to implement similar thing for windows phone 7 in a custom way?

I see 9gag app by Rudy Huyn (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/9gag/91000c5c-9943-43b8-aa65-7609d91057ef) does it but I'm not sure how he does it. When I click remove ads in this app it take me to the paid version of the app. But there are no separate two apps in the store, like we do - one app as normal and another as Pro.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish a trial app. This way users can download it for free and then buy if they like it.

Here you can fin tutorial for creating trial apps - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967558(v=vs.105).aspx .
´

Now I can also show you how to take the user to the Store to see the app's listing with the Buy button:

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Please note, that this will work only with published app, not in debugging (the listing is not yet there in Store). Also - there are more useful tasks like MarketplaceReviewTask, you can take a look at it too.

UPDATE:
We figured a second way to do this while maintaining the free status of the app in store. Basically you need to publish a free app and a private paid app. Now using MarketplaceDetailTask you can point the user to the paid app by supplying it's GUID:

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();

marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "PAID-APPS-GUID";
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;

marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

That said, you need to publish the paid one first to find out it's Store GUID that you can then insert into the public free one.

Comment: You are correct. But by human psychology people don't even look at paid apps. They will look for what is free. Once they use the app for free and find it useful they may buy it. I don't want to go the trial way. Did you get a chance to see the workflow for 9gag?

Comment: I suspect the paid version is listed privately in the store and he uses the MarketplaceDetailTask to show it manually. But he has indeed two versions in store - one paid and one free. See here - this is the paid app - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/9gag/3da887f2-7b51-4ced-9104-0ca2446ff1cf , and this is the free one - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/9gag/91000c5c-9943-43b8-aa65-7609d91057ef ,. The IDs are different, so those are two different apps.

Comment: You rock!!!  Do you think, it is possible to submit two apps with the same name? I tried once, it did not allow me to do so. May this paid app is private, that's it might have allowed it. I will try. Please update your answer with the option you are saying in the above comments and I will mark it as answer. Thanks you!

Comment: Done, answer updated :-) . You should definitly publish the paid private one first, so that you can get the app's GUID that you will insert into the MarketplaceDetailTask :-) . You are welcome ;-)