# Is it possible to publish two apps with the same name?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

Im' wondering if there is a way to post to apps with the same name at the Windows Phone Store, as is suggested in the post linked below:

[Is there a way to implement custom in app upgrade in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089924/is-there-a-way-to-implement-custom-in-app-upgrade-in-windows-phone-7)

Does someone know how they did this thing of "posting one private and one public, with the same name"? Or they didn't do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Submitting two apps was a workaround widely used for WP7 to have a free and paid version of a same app. WP8 introduced in-app purchases, making the previous trick obsolete

Comment: Hmm, right. Guess I'll have to publish two apps then. Thanks!